# Orbit of morphisms $A \to k$ biject to morphism on the invariants $A^G \to k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative algebra over a field $k$, and $G$ a group acting on $A$, so I have a homomorphism $G \to \operatorname{Aut}_k(A)$. Then $G$ also acts on $\operatorname{Hom}_k(A, k)$ by
$$
(g \varphi)(x) = \varphi(g^{-1}x).
$$
Then I have a well-defined map on the orbits
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_k(A, k)/G \to \operatorname{Hom}_k(A^G, k)
$$
sending the orbit of a morphism $\varphi \colon A \to k$ to its restriction to $A^G$. This is well defined, since two morphism in the same $G$-orbit are the same on the invariants $A^G$.

I am wondering if this is always a bijection, or if one can formulate conditions under which it is a bijection.

This question is motivated by the following: if one has an affine variety $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$ over $k$ with an action of a group $G$, then I've heard the quotient variety is defined by $X/G = \operatorname{Spec} A^G$. Taking $k$-points, I'd expect the result I am asking about to hold, or perhaps at least if $k$ is algebraically closed and $A$ is reduced.

Comment: I assume that $G$ is finite (otherwise, even injectivity is unlikely, as you can see (e.g.) by letting the additive group of $k$ acting on the polynomial ring $k\left[x\right]$ by translation). Then, see https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/l49-combinatorially.pdf for injectivity.

Comment: I think surjectivity would require $k$ to be algebraically closed, or maybe even a stronger statement. Otherwise, taking $A = k\left[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\right]$ and $G = S_n$ would allow you to solve an $n$-degree polynomial equation by extending a ring homomorphism from $A^G$ to $k$.

Comment: Thank you. I see the reference in your link proves it is a bijection if $k$ is algebraically closed, $G$ is profinite and the action is continuous, which is the kind of statement I was looking for.

Comment: Ah, right -- I forgot about that part of the lemma!